# NSMutableArray addObject: Localizable string

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nslocalizedstring

I wanted to ask a short question.

Is this possible or do I have to change anything?:

```
[self.category addObject:NSLocalizedString(@"Accessories", nil)];
```

This is an object in an tableView that should use the content from a .strings file

Comment: Wouldn't this be _very_ simple for you to test if it's possible? ;)

Comment: it doesn't work. That's the problem. I want to know if the error is here or in the .strings file.

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", NSLocalizedString(@"Accessories", nil)); - does it work?

Comment: then your strings file isn't in the target/corrupt or the string isn't there

Comment: according to your strings file (As seen below) "Accessories" = "Accessories";

Comment: **Don't say "It doesn't work" without describing WHAT doesn't work.  Give the error message, at the very least, or describe in detail what expected result does not occur.**

Comment: OK, there is no error message. Build succeeds. In my tableView, there should be displayed the content of the strings file. But it doesn't show the content, it shows, what I have typed in for key.

Comment: Hey guys, I got it! I don't know what the error was but i have rewritten my code my .strings file and then it worked. Thank you really much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

the code works ;)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        id category = [NSMutableArray array];
        [category addObject:NSLocalizedString(@"Accessories", nil)];
        NSLog(@"%@", category);
    }
}
```

self.category isn't nil you said and so it must be the strings file:
maybe the file isn't in the target/corrupt or the string isn't there

Comment: yes so it is nil... where do you create self.category

Comment: the NSMutable Array is created in my .h file: @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *category;

Comment: And here's whats in my .m file : -(NSMutableArray *)category
{
    if (!category)
        
    {
        category = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }
    return category;
}

Comment: I have this in my .m file: @synthesize category;

Comment: So what can I then do?

Comment: When I run my app, the text in the tableView is still in the native language and not in german like expected

Comment: attach the strings file

Comment: "Accessories" = "Accessories";
"Blouses" = "Blusen";
"Bras" = "BHs";
"Caps" = "Caps";
"Cardigans & Sweaters" = "Cardigans & Sweaters";
"Dresses" = "Kleider";
"Hot-Pants" = "Hot-Pants";
"Jackets & Coats" = "Jacken & Mäntel";
"Jackettes" = "Jackettes";
"Jeans & Pants" = "Jeans & Hosen";
"Leggins" = "Leggins";
"Longsleeves" = "Longsleeves";
"Shirts" = "Hemden";
"Shoes" = "Schuhe";
"Shorts" = "Shorts";
"Skirts" = "Röcke";
"Suits" = "Anzüge";
"Swimwear" = "Bademode";
"Tights" = "Strumpfhosen";
"Tops" = "Tops";
"T-Shirts" = "T-Shirts";
"Underwear" = "Unterwäsche";

Comment: and the file is in the target?

Comment: It's in my supporting files folder

Comment: according to your strings file "Accessories" = "Accessories";

Comment: Yes, but still all other objects are in english and not in german

Comment: then give us your project because it works just fine for all of us

Comment: @Daji-Djan where should I upload it?

Comment: upload it to some file sharing website .. or to your dropbox or whatever - then post the link here

Comment: else mail it to me :) -- dominik@pich.info

Comment: @Daji-Djan I've send it to you via E-Mail. For all the others, you can find a project that works like this in my github: https://github.com/Sam0711er

Comment: Hey guys, I got it! I don't know what the error was but i have rewritten my code my .strings file and then it worked. Thank you really much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Of course.. probably the error is somewhere else. `NSLocalizedString` is just a macro that at compile time is replace by `[[NSBundle mainBundle] localizedStringForKey:(key) value:@"" table:nil]`. As you ca see is a simple method that returns a string for a key at runtime. 
There is nothing wrong in your code. Check in your localization file for a key that matches perfectly the one you provide.

Comment: I tried, but it won't work :( I#ve also tried it with different objects but it won't work

Comment: What do you mean by"I've tried with different objects"

Comment: Are you sure that you have totally understood how localization process works?

Comment: I hope so. I've done it with this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014

Comment: Ok, restore the simulator to default state, make a clean build of your project (shift+cmd+K), select German in language settings of the SIM, relaunch. If still in english i would check the directories of your project to check if there is a de.lproj directory with inside the localized strings file.

Comment: have done everything. Still doesn't work. I have a de.lproj file in my Projects folder. Inside the de.lproj folder the is my Localizable.strings file. All there. But it still doesn't work

Comment: @Daji-Djan What can I do now?

Comment: Hey guys, I got it! I don't know what the error was but i have rewritten my code my .strings file and then it worked. Thank you really much for your help!

Comment: Good! Glad that you find the solution